# Screen not correctly detecting border

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, av-cable

I'm swapping out my screens today for some new ones. The first 2 work fine. The 3rd is doing this (see row numbers being cut off on the left):

What's causing this and how do I fix it?

I'm guessing it might be down to the cable (this particular screen is connected via VGA)?

[image]

Comment: Hello there. Is your resolution on the third screen the exact native resolution? If your monitor is over 2048x1536, VGA wont be able to sync with it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears when using analog video signal in which sync signals don't match video signal accurately. The image is shifted horizontally and/or vertically. If left side is cut off, like in your case, a black margin will appear on the right side.

This problem can be mitigated by adjusting screen position in monitor's menu. I can't post exact instructions because menus differ between monitor manufacturers and models, but it shouldn't be hard to find.

Please note that VGA signal will be noisy when used with modern high-resolution monitors, it's just not suitable. Consider switching to a digital connection (HDMI, DisplayPort or DVI-D) if possible.

Comment: Any modern monitor wont have any shift in vert/hor position if the input resolution matches the native resolution. The type of cable is irrelevant.

Comment: @NatsuKage Some modern monitors automatically adjust these offsets when they detect the signal, but this feature isn't mandatory nor perfect. This issue is a remnant from the CRT age, when the electron beam was controlled by sync signals. Digital to analog converters in LCDs still have to rely on these signals being accurate.